# How to remove duplicate words from a file in ant?

Tags: ant

How to remove duplicate words from a file in ant.

Comment: To be clear: you want ant code that will take a file and remove duplicate words? If so, can you give an example of the sorts of file you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the problem for Ant. The purpose of Ant is to automate build process.

Comment: i did it now by unix linus,first i broke each line on the basis of space so this gave me one word per line then i used uniq.i even did it in excel,but i could not do it in ant...@rlandster my example is as if my file contains following words Ant,Apache,Java,Maven,Ant,C,DS,ANT....as you can see there are 3 occurances of ANT but i want only one so i should be able to remove rest two...